# Unable to connect to Spark UI on EMR

Tags: hadoop, ssh, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I have set up my SSH tunnel as per the instructions on the EMR console using `ssh -i ~/SparkTest.pem -ND 8157 hadoop@ec2-52-1-245-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com`. I have also set up FoxyProxy as per the instructions.

I can access the Hadoop ResourceManager on `http://master-public-dns-name:8088/`, and I can see my applications running.

Clicking the Master URL for any of the Applications, or any of the node HTTP URLs leads to a 'problem loading page', with the SSH tunnel giving the following output `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`.

Should I be using the YARN ResourceManager instead? Where can I find the URL for this? Is there a configuration step that I somehow missed when setting up my proxy and SSH tunnel?

Cheers.

Comment: Could it be a security group issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to SSH and to get the Spark UI. Try this

```
ssh -i ~/SparkTest.pem -D 8157 hadoop@ec2-52-1-245-67.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This works for me